# Text box values when editing GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which is pretty functioning except for one thing: when I click the Edit link button, it appears a list of textboxes to edit the values as I want. But, when I click the update button and do `((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text` (for example), it returns me the value that was there before the I edited the textbox!

Any idea of how to access the new texts of the textboxes?

Comment: Can you please provide some more Code? Your call should return the actual Text, which is set to the first Textbox on 3rd cell in your row. But what should it do?

Answer (score 0):

Hey You have to do on `Gridview_RowUpdating` command like that

```
 protected void gvSalaryDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {    
     ((TextBox)gvSalaryDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtgvSalaryHeadValue")).Text;
    }
```

and Aspx page shoul follow like that.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblgvSalaryHeadValue" runat="server" Text='<%# ((SalaryDetails)Container.DataItem).HeadValue %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtgvSalaryHeadValue" runat="server" Text='<%# ((SalaryDetails)Container.DataItem).HeadValue %>'></asp:TextBox>
         </EditItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

Hope it Helps you..

Comment: Where should I add the TemplateField?

Comment: And what it "SalaryDetails" in your context?

Comment: Template field is Aspx page Under the Gridview->Column.And "SalaryDetails" is Entity You can set your text over here or Use Eval.Hope clear